# creating pull down menu in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have this requirement where i have to show a menu when users slide their finger down the screen. Just like viewing notifications in android and iOS.

If not the same thing may be any alternatives that i can use.

I'm new to windows phone development. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

While it can be done on your own, it's a pain to do well, and Telerik has already done this - check out their Data Bound ListBox control - http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/databoundlistbox.aspx